# How to compile an image file as icon into an EXE using GTK+ as GUI?

Tags: gtk

I know how to set up an image as the icon of a GtkWindow.

```
GtkWindow * window;
gtk_window_set_icon_from_file(window, "icon.png", NULL);
```

and place icon.png together with the exe.

But what if **I don't want to keep that image file in my folder**? I want it somehow bundled inside the exe file.

I know this can be done with qrc in Qt. Can I do this in GTK+ too?

Answer (score 5):

I know how to do it now.

First, I have to convert that image into plain code.

Say I want to make `icon.png` as the icon.

Run this command to convert it as an variable named `icon_1`. Grab that binary if you don't have it.

```
gdk-pixbuf-csource --raw --name=icon_1 icon.png
```

It will show on the command prompt. But I suppose you want to save it to a file. So

```
gdk-pixbuf-csource --raw --name=icon_1 icon.png>icon.c
```

will do the job in Windows.

Now that variable `icon_1` is ready to use.

Next step. Call `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_inline()` to create a new `GdkPixbuf *` from `icon_1`.

```
GdkPixbuf * icon_title = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_inline(-1, icon_1, false, NULL);
```

You can now call `gtk_window_set_icon()` with that newly created `icon_title` to set up the icon of the window.

```
gtk_window_set_icon(window, icon_title);
```

Also remember that if you keep `icon_1` in a standalone C file, you have to include `glib.h` so that it can be compiled because it uses type `guint8`, and extern that variable before using so that it can be linked.

More details:

https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/unstable/gdk-pixbuf-Image-Data-in-Memory.html#gdk-pixbuf-new-from-inline

Comment: This has been deprecated for a while now

Answer (score 3):

Use [GResource](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html)

An example .gresource.xml might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
    <gresource prefix="/com/example/myapp">
        <file>icon.png</file>
    </gresource>
</gresources>
```

Then compile it to C:

```
glib-compile-resources.exe myapp.gresource.xml --generate-source --target=resources.c
```

And include resources.c in you applications sources

Then to use the embedded file as the window icon:

```
gtk_window_set_icon_from_file (window, "resource:///com/example/myapp/icon.png", NULL);
```

*Also Consider setting the icon with gtk_window_set_default_icon_from_file to apply it to dialogs as well*

Answer (score 1):

This question is relatively old, but nevertheless I stumbled over it while googling for a similar problem. So, perhaps the following is helpful, which relies on the answer of @DrOli who describes a very versatile approach.
First convert PNG to XPM using ImageMagicks convert

```
convert about.png about.xpm
```

Include the new file into your code and create the pixbuf the gtkmm way

```
#include <gdkmm/pixbuf.h>
#include "about.xpm"

Glib::RefPtr< Gdk::Pixbuf > logo = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_xpm_data(about);
```

Voila ...

Comment: It gives a lot of warnings about converting a string constant to 'char*'. But it works nonetheless. :D

Comment: @munikarmanish yes you are right, I forgot to mention that the first lines have to be changed:  
`/* XPM */`  
`static const char *about[] = {`  
`/* columns rows colors chars-per-pixel */ `

Answer (score 0):

We are a bit new to this, and needed to accomplish essentially the same thing, but arrived at a different approach.

Notably, convert the png(s) to  xpm(s), then load/copy the "raw xpm(s)" info into your raw code as a "variable", then in GTK etc use gdk_pixbuf_new_from_xpm_data() ... etc.

This way the raw xpm is compiled as part of your code, and then it won't need to search externally for files, etc.

It means loosing some features from png that xpm can't support, but it's dead easy, and even us "non IT types" can manage it.

This also allows direct access to the "image" as it can be edited as "text" in the code, it is easy to make variations and additional icons, etc., and it is fairly easy to alter the icon/image "in real time" programmatically.

It is also very portable.  For example, we also use this in Gtk-Fortran on Windows ... works beautifully.