# How to set an icon on Linux in C language (the C file) for the alone running program that does not load any external image file?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gtk

I tried deleting the external ICO file and reopen the program, it no longer displayed the icon. I successfully placed the icon for my program with the `gtk_window_set_default_icon_from_file()` function, but then my program was dependent on the external file. How to fix?

This in my C file:

```
gtk_window_set_default_icon_from_file ("b.ico", NULL);
```

*One By One. This is my project:*

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_VL9uiG1Q67VZxWuVkXza1ywSeTaNhA-?usp=sharing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile an image file as icon into an EXE using GTK+ as GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114660/how-to-compile-an-image-file-as-icon-into-an-exe-using-gtk-as-gui)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195413/discussion-on-question-by-merson-su-how-to-set-an-icon-on-linux-in-c-language-t).