# Is it possible to add resource file (.rc) in code-blocks IDE as like in Microsoft Visual Studio using VC++ for include images in project

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gtk, codeblocks

I am working on C++ application in Ubuntu OS using Gtkmm-3.0 Library for GUI, which is written using Code-Blocks IDE. Is it possible to add resource file or .rc file for images as like in Windows OS using VC++ (MFC Library)? Now am referring Images by keeping in Folder in Code-Blocks, so that along with final executable file in Ubuntu need to give image folder to Run application. Is there any method to add images directly in source code to give single executable file? Any way to do in CODE-BLOCKS IDE?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code::Blocks is an IDE, while your issue is about resources. In Windows you need just to add the `.res` file to your *project*. But I'm afraid there's no "resources" thing in Linux. You must load the icons & images at run-time.

Comment: How to load icons & images at run-time?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114660/how-to-compile-an-image-file-as-icon-into-an-exe-using-gtk-as-gui